# How to reduce this code from two functions into one using for loop?

Tags: javascript

Hi there can someone help me please I have this two functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    sizeNestable(); 
}); 

$('#nestable1, #nestable2').change(function() {
    sizeNestable();
});

function sizeNestable() {

    var n3 = $('#nestable1').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
    var n4 = $('#nestable2').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 

    var smallest; 
    var largest; 

    if(n3.size() > n4.size()) { 
        largest = n3; 
        smallest = n4; 
    } else { 
        largest = n4; 
        smallest = n3; 
    } 

    for(var i = 0; i < smallest.size(); i++) { 
        if(smallest.eq(i).height()  > largest.eq(i).height()) { 
            largest.eq(i).height(smallest.eq(i).height()); 
        } else { 
            smallest.eq(i).height(largest.eq(i).height()); 
        }
    }
}
```

That was the first one and the second function is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   sizeNestable2(); 
}); 

$('#nestable3, #nestable4').change(function() {
   sizeNestable2();
});

function sizeNestable2() {

    var n3 = $('#nestable3').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
    var n4 = $('#nestable4').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 

    var smallest; 
    var largest; 

    if(n3.size() > n4.size()) { 
        largest = n3; 
        smallest = n4; 
    } else { 
        largest = n4; 
        smallest = n3; 
    } 

    for(var i = 0; i < smallest.size(); i++) { 
        if(smallest.eq(i).height()  > largest.eq(i).height()) { 
            largest.eq(i).height(smallest.eq(i).height()); 
        } else { 
            smallest.eq(i).height(largest.eq(i).height()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me how can I make one function from this two is there a way to reduce this code because it will not look good every time   I need the nestable to add another function..?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to pass the `selector` to `sizeNestable` function.

Here is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    sizeNestable('#nestable1', '#nestable2');
    sizeNestable('#nestable3', '#nestable4');
}); 

$('#nestable1, #nestable2').change(function() {
    sizeNestable('#nestable1', '#nestable2');
});
$('#nestable3, #nestable4').change(function() {
    sizeNestable('#nestable3', '#nestable4');
});

function sizeNestable(id1, id2) {

    var n3 = $(id1).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
    var n4 = $(id2).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 

    var smallest; 
    var largest; 

    if(n3.size() > n4.size()) { 
        largest = n3; 
        smallest = n4; 
    } else { 
        largest = n4; 
        smallest = n3; 
    } 

    for(var i = 0; i < smallest.size(); i++) { 
        if(smallest.eq(i).height()  > largest.eq(i).height()) { 
            largest.eq(i).height(smallest.eq(i).height()); 
        } else { 
            smallest.eq(i).height(largest.eq(i).height()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the only difference seems to be the assignments to `n3` and `n4` you can simply pass two variables to the generic `sizeNestable` function to correctly set them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    sizeNestable('nestable1', 'nestable2');
    sizeNestable('nestable3', 'nestable4');
}); 

$('#nestable1, #nestable2').change(function() {
    sizeNestable('nestable1', 'nestable2');
});

$('#nestable3, #nestable4').change(function() {
    sizeNestable('nestable3', 'nestable4');
});

function sizeNestable(container1, container2) {
    var n3 = $('#' + container1).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
    var n4 = $('#' + container2).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 

    // rest of your function stays the same...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `sizeNestable` and `sizeNestable2` does everything the same. The only difference is that the first one is targeting `#nestable1` and `#nestable2` while the second one is targeting `#nestable3` and `#nestable4`.

You can just add two parameters to the function and use those for setting the `n`s.

```
function sizeNestable(nestable1, nestable2) {
  const n1 = $(nestable1).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');
  const n2 = $(nestable2).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');

  ...
}

sizeNestable('#nestable1', '#nestable2');
sizeNestable('#nestable3', '#nestable4');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you had better edit selector like this

```
<input class="nestable" id="nestable1" data-target="#nestable2" >
<input class="nestable" id="nestable2" data-target="#nestable1" >
<input class="nestable" id="nestable3" data-target="#nestable4" >
<input class="nestable" id="nestable4" data-target="#nestable3" >
```

and in your javascript

```
    $('.nestable').change(function() {
        var $number = jQuery(this).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
        var $number2 = jQuery(jQuery(this).data('target')).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');
 //other code here
    });
```